# How to find the highest value of an array index of an HTML class using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a HTML form where the elements are added dynamically. One of them is a select element which is an array that has a class name **interfacesArray** with the index value inside braces. For example, a particular select element may be written as:

```js
var index = $("#container .row").length -1;
var ifId = $("#interfacesArray\\[0\\]\\.id").clone();
ifId.attr("id", "interfacesArray" + index+".id");
ifId.attr("name", "interfacesArray[" + index+"].id");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="interfacesArray[3].id" name="interfacesArray[3].id" class="form-control" required="required">
```

How do I retrieve the highest value of the index of the array where the indexes may not be continuous? For example, if there are select elements with index 0,1,5,2,3, I would like to select the value 5. Thank you.

The issue with this is that with some deletions and additions, it is possible to have arrays of the same index. So, I would like to take the highest index and simply add 1 to the next dynamic field.

Comment: could you please tell me how you add html select element dynamically in to the form ??

Comment: Please can you share all the relevant code (including JavaScript) that you have tried so far Monty. This will allow us reproduce your issue.

Comment: Thanks for adding the JavaScript. I have turned it into a code snippet for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Loop through all elements and find the highest index

```
let highestIndex = -1;
$('select.form-control').each(function(){ // you might change the selector
  const currentName = this.attr('name');
  const currentBracketIndex = currentName.indexOf('[')+1;
  const currentID = currentName.slice(currentBracketIndex,currentBracketIndex + 1);
  highestIndex = Math.max(highestIndex,parseInt(currentID));
})
```

Answer (score 1):

If the index is unique and you are adding element dynamically. one thing you could do.

add data attr in html elements which hold the index values. like following

```
<select data-index="3" id="interfacesArray[3].id" name="interfacesArray[3].id" class="form-control" required="required">
```

Then query the select elements and find out the highest index by comparing the data-index attrs